# Aurelia: How to track if @children elements are loaded?

Tags: aurelia

I have custom Tabs functionality, but after the update of Aurelia to rc-1.0.x, there is issue with listing data from @children decorator.

My code look something like:
       import {inject, customElement, children} from 'aurelia-framework';

```
    @customElement('tabs')
    @inject(Element)
    @children({name:'tabs', selector: "tab"})

    export class Tabs  {
      activeTab = undefined;

      constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
      }

      attached() {
        console.log(this.tabs); // Return undefined on promise resolve!!!
        this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
          if (tab.active) {
            this.activeTab = tab;
          }

          tab.hide();
        });

        this.activeTab.show();

      }
```

On first load everything is working just fine, and **this.tabs** is an array of items, as expected.

Next if I do a server request, when promise is resolved **this.tabs** console logs undefined.

If I set timeout it fix the issue, but is that the correct way?

Also I noticed in the html, that the **repeat.for** statement is executed, which give me a clue that **this.tabs** is received with some delay, after the attached function is handled.

The html:

```
<template>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs m-b-1">
    <li repeat.for="tab of tabs">
      <a href="#" click.trigger="$parent.onTabClick(tab)">
        ${tab.name & t}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <slot></slot>
</template>
```

So is there a way to make that work with the Aurelia bind or attached methods or some more elegant way, instead to check the value of this.tabs with a timeout function?

Comment: Where is the promise resolved in your code?

Comment: Tabs are part of other custom element. The promise is resolved in other core file which, we track with bindingEngine and update the model of that custom element.

Comment: Would you mind creating a quick repro of your issue using gist.run? I've created a basic setup for you to start from here: https://gist.run/?id=cbf7a20cd866d4c2a56ddda80ab26764 Just add in the code needed, click "Fork to Public Gist" and post the link as a comment.

Comment: I'm afraid I cant do that. See I inherit the code from other developer and the core file has very complex logic, so it is not so easy to put it in gist. I reorganize the logic for tabs and make it work without the timeout, but think this is Aurelia issue anyway. The @children is not resolved at the moment when bind or attached has been trigered. Anyway Thanks for the support and hope to clear that issue in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be an adequate use-case for the Task Queue (but if someone more knowledgeable thinks otherwise, let me know). I have had to use the Task Queue before when accessing bindable values from inside of `attached` and your instance looks basically the same (except you're accessing them using `@children`).

The TaskQueue will push your logic to the end of the processing stack. So theoretically this means it will wait for Aurelia to finish running its internal logic for bindings and possibly children decorator resolution and then run your code.

There might be a better solution, but I have used this before to get out of a similar situation as I mentioned earlier and have yet to find a better solution that fixes the problem, specifically in regards to accessing dynamic values inside of `attached`.

```
import {TaskQueue} from 'aurelia-framework';

@customElement('tabs')
@inject(Element, TaskQueue)
@children({name:'tabs', selector: "tab"})

export class Tabs  {
  activeTab = undefined;

  constructor(element, taskQueue) {
    this.element = element;
    this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
  }

  attached() {
    this.taskQueue.queueMicroTask(() =>{
        this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
            if (tab.active) {
                this.activeTab = tab;
            }

            tab.hide();
         });

         this.activeTab.show();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! As I say I refactor the logic and do this functionality a lot more simpler. Anyway, what you say about the taskQueue will help me solve another problem. I was also wandering is there a listener that detects whenever this.tabs is populated, and then run function that will do the iteration? Perhaps something that is used by repeat.for attribute in the html?